# Putting if statement inside new instance of class

Tags: c#

Is it possible to put somehow if statement inside new class body?

```
this.inventory.Items.Select(x=> new StandardItem
{
   ItemNumber = x.ItNo,
   if(isAltered){
      PartNumber = x.PaNo
   }else{
      PartNumber = x.PaReplacedNo
   }
}
```

Above code returns compilation error.

Comment: there seems to be a bug, i guess you want to assign PaReplacedNo if the item was altered, currently you are assigning it if it wasn't altered.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) instead:

```
this.inventory.Items.Select(x=> new StandardItem
{
   ItemNumber = x.ItNo,
   PartNumber = isAltered ? x.PaNo : x.PaReplacedNo
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)...

```
this.inventory.Items.Select(x=> new StandardItem
{
    ItemNumber = x.ItNo,
    PartNumber = isAltered ? x.PaNo : x.PaReplacedNo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the conditional operator

```
PartNumber = isAltered ? x.PaNo : x.PaReplaceNo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator as an in-line if-else:

```
this.inventory.Items.Select(x=> new StandardItem
{
  ItemNumber = x.ItNo,
  PartNumber = isAltered ? x.PaNo : x.PaReplacedNo
}
```